# resize all objects inside view in titanium

Tags: android, ios, titanium, titanium-mobile, autoresize

I have a view that contains my layout . when a button is pressed the main view is resized but all it children keep the same height and width. How can I resize all objects that are inside the main view?

for example when I have this:

```
var view = Ti.UI.createView({
  height:deviceHeight,
  width:deviceWidth
});

view.add(Ti.UI.createView({
  height:Ti.UI.SIZE,
  width:Ti.UI.SIZE
}));
```

how can I for example resize the secunde view that is added to the firs one?

I'm developing my app in titanium in classic mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you specified `SIZE` as the size for a view it will keep that size. As you didn't specify it needed to have a size based on the parent.

The only way to do this is, if you specify the height and width as a percentage.

If your content is in fact dynamic you could trick it.

When the button is pressed convert your `view` to an image with `var image = view.toImage()`.

Then, hide all the content you've added and insert the image into your view:

```
var image = view.toImage()

var img = Ti.UI.createImageView({
    height: '100%',
    width: '100%',
    image: image
});
view.add(img);
```

Then you can resize your `view` and the content will resize too.

Comment: thanks it worked. I have found a problem in you're code. Ore you change from Ti.UI.createView to Ti.UI.createImageView ore instead of image : image you have to set backgroundImage : image

Comment: One more question. in android you're code takes a lot of time to execute. is there a faster way to do that?

Comment: which one, the image hack or the percentage solution

Comment: I think it is the image hack. when I use the view.toImage().

Comment: yeah `toImage` isn't the fastest. You can also pre-generate this image in the background before the button is clicked. But that only makes sense if the content cannot change

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128850/discussion-between-manuel-rodrigues-and-rene-pot).

Comment: Please join on www.tislack.org and contact me (Wraldpyk) there